PyTesseract unable to read simple images
I was able to preprocess an image to make the text clear. The result was this:

However, even testing different configuration options, it still gives bd4\n as result. Here is the line where this image is read:
pytesseract.image_to_string(thr, config=r'--oem 3 --psm 6 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789')

I've tested different methods proposed in other questions here, but none have worked so far.
